# Periodic DNS name resolution issue

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, godaddy

I have a domain with an A record for `api.mydomain.com` and it works fine about 99.9% of the time. Over the last few months an issue occurs where the DNS name resolution starts to fail. It continues to fail for about 10 minutes for many users across the country and then it fixes itself. This has happened 5 or 6 times since September.

The nameservers are with GoDaddy. I have called their support but it takes too long to get to technical assistance and the issue is gone before I can talk to them. They won't troubleshoot it if it is working once on the line

Traceroute fails for the domain as well with `Unable to resolve target system name`

The only thing I can think of is that this is an issue with the nameservers but I haven't had any success getting support. What else could this be and how can I troubleshoot it more deeply? It would be a pain but I could move the nameservers to Azure

[image]

Comment: What is the TTL?

Comment: TTL 1 hour @GregAskew